# Is there a jQuery stand-alone Ajax module?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get jQuery's Ajax module? The point is I do not need the whole library, but only its Ajax module (I need to include this module in several iframes).

Comment: Any issue if you choose to include the whole lib? Its not that heavy.

Comment: Even if you use it in multiple iFrames, it will only be downloaded once. The browser is usually that clever. Use the minified version. It is 26kb only.

Comment: iframes are from different subdomains (like sss.exemp.net and ggg.exemp.net)

Comment: the whole lib is not an option. that's why i am here asking about the part only.

Comment: If you host jQuery on a single domain, this is not going to be a problem.

Comment: here's how: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2013/05/build-jquery-with-ajax-only.html

Comment: i posted an answer below. =)

Answer (score 37):

## **Update 2016**

You can use this tool to build your own custom jQuery version.

[**jQuery Builder**](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/)

As of jQuery 2.1.1

Full file sized unminified is: **241.55 Kb**

Ajax Only minified is: **49.60 Kb**

That is a **5x** reduction in size.

[image]

Comment: Whats going on with that form? If I select `none` I get `Filesize: 187.84 Kb / Gzip: 55.69 Kb` which should be 0, if I select only ajax then I get even more `Filesize: 222.03 Kb / Gzip: 66.51 Kb` there is **NO** option that generates ` 49.60 Kb`

Comment: @samayo I edited my post so you can check your answer.

Answer (score 13):

Another option would be to use the built-in `fetch` API provided by the browser.

Here is an example snippet:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/users.json', {
  method: 'POST', 
  mode: 'cors', 
  redirect: 'follow',
  body: JSON.stringify({
     user: {
       firstName: 'john',
       lastName: 'doe'
     }
  }),
  headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
}).then(function() {
  /* handle response */
});
```

[This blog post](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) is a great introduction to the API and shows more use cases.

`fetch` doesn't have full cross-browser support yet (I think mainly IE and Safari are lacking), but there is polyfill that you can use until that day comes.

`fetch` polyfill: https://github.com/github/fetch

Older browsers will also need a `Promise` polyfill ([one option](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill), [another option](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise)).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using fetch in production. I just faced some weird problems on safari (on both macOS Sierra and iOS 10). Maybe it's just me being stupid, but I don't think it's worth the debugging time.

Comment: I mentioned this in the post, and suggested using a polyfill for now. Thanks for highlighting the issue though.

Answer (score 12):

As Darin already says, it's all or nothing. JQuery's Ajax functions are closely intertwined with the rest of the functionality.

There are a few other, stand-alone Ajax libraries around like [Matt Kruse's Ajax toolbox](http://www.ajaxtoolbox.com/) - maybe that helps.

I would consider loading the full jQuery library. If you link to [jQuery on a CDN,](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) loading times will be minuscule.

Comment: personally i like amplify.js

Comment: @johnSmith Amplify.js relies on jQuery to perform Ajax request, just the opposite of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 8):

As of jQuery 1.8 you can do it: [LINK](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery)

Answer (score 4):

You can view standard javascript alternatives to jQuery at [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)

For example the alternative to `$.ajax` `post` is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

And the alternative to `$.ajax` `get` is:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = request.responseText;
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

Answer (score 3):

I've created a custom build of jQuery 1.7.1 here:

https://github.com/dtjm/jquery/tree/ajaxonly

Comment: [I've built it](https://github.com/thorsummoner/jquery-ajax) for people who can't do so, its from jQ-1.7.1, a whole [41Kb minified](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thorsummoner/jquery-ajax/jquery-ajax/jquery.min.js) No guarantees!

Answer (score 3):

AMD user please read [this](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/jquery-using-only-what-you-need/), my answer is for building a single file.
Or just use this library: [ded / reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest) (4 KB, min & gzip)

---

1. Download [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) and run `npn i`
2. Open `/src/jquery.js` and remove any moudle you don't want, but keep `"./exports/amd"`, `"./exports/global"`

   ```
   define([
       "./ajax",
       "./ajax/xhr",
       "./ajax/script",
       "./ajax/jsonp",
       "./exports/amd",
       "./exports/global"
   ], function (jQuery) {
       "use strict";
       return jQuery;
   });
   ```
3. Run `grunt custom:-sizzle`
4. Goto `/dist` and take your build

Modules in your build now:

- core
- deferred
- ajax

Size:

- just build: 85 KB
- build with min: 26 KB
- build with min & gzip: 10 KB

Comment: build: https://gist.github.com/zcyzcy88/393ca7dc76d22f3e5a4592f59f675ad1

Comment: Nice approach !

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** This library was removed from GitHub, I would recommend using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead. All modern browsers support it without IE.

***Old answer:***
You can try **[AJAJ](https://github.com/BroadBrander/ajaj)**. It's a very tiny(less than 1kb gzipped) library to make ajax calls. And its syntax is very similar to jQuery.

For example:

```
ajaj({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/path/to/request",
  data: {
    name: "AJAJ",
    version: "1.0.0",
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  fail: function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really really want just the Ajax parts of jQuery you can get the code from their repository (https://github.com/jquery/jquery), glancing at it you would want to look at "ajax.js" and "core.js" in the "src" directory. You would then want to compile them together with the closure compiler or something.

But as others stated, it would be a lot easier to just load it from one of the CDNs (jQuery, Google, Microsoft) which most users will have cached anyway.

Answer (score 1):

YES, I just did mine, 
http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2013/05/build-jquery-with-ajax-only.html

you only need these files (resulting minified is about 30Kb):

```
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/intro.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/core.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/callbacks.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/deferred.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/support.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/data.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/event.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/serialize.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/ajax.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/ajax/xhr.js
/d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/exports.js
 /d/dev/javascript/jquery/jquery/src/outro.js
```

Comment: Thanks for referencing this post.  I put a project up on github that is based on this.  It does some global renaming to avoid conflicts https://github.com/dbennett455/jqAjax

Comment: 30kb is a LOT for just ajax()

Comment: this is jquery ajax.

Answer (score 0):

It's all or nothing. Of course jquery is open source and you could extract the part you are interested in in your own library (good luck with this). You may consider using a CDN which will ensure that most users will already have it cached in their browsers so you shouldn't be concerned about size.

Comment: Nothing wrong, it just could be a challenging task and when a new version of jquery comes out you might need to start all over if you want to use this new version.

Comment: @fgf only if you really, really have some extra time on your hands and really don't know what to do with it (like, a month or two) ripping parts out of jQuery is worth considering.

Comment: jQuery is modular now, so this answer is no longer relevant: https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery

Answer (score 0):

There is none out of the box but you can of course cut and paste from the existing file and then minimize it.

If you are just worried about the size of the library serving it from a CDN from Google, MS or jQuery will probably require less data traffic as most browsers already have the files cached.