# Extract Ajax Part from jQuery Library

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My question is related to below post, which doesn't have clear answer yet.

[Is there only Ajax part of jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132163/is-there-only-ajax-part-of-jquery)

I would like to user only Ajax part of jQuery and do not want to use the whole library. Can anyone help to for the same.

In one answer  from the above post I found this ajax library
https://github.com/dtjm/jquery/tree/ajaxonly

As mentioned there, I tried below commands but, I do not have password to extract the jquery part.

```
git clone https://dtjm@github.com/dtjm/jquery.git
git checkout ajaxonly
make
```

It asks for the password. Does any expert know, how to get Ajax part?
Or any other easiest way to extract ajax?

Comment: follow this steps:
http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2013/05/build-jquery-with-ajax-only.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions for building a custom version of jQuery on the [jQuery github page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#how-to-build-your-own-jquery). (note that this only works with jQuery 1.9+)

After you have cloned the repository and installed grunt you should be able to then build a version of jQuery that only includes ajax with:

`grunt custom:-css,-deprecated,-dimensions,-effects,-event-alias,-offset,-sizzle`

If you need the convenience of an `ajax` wrapper/normalizing without jQuery, my suggestion would be to use [ender](http://enderjs.com/) and build a package with ajax library like [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest). This will reduce the filesize of your ajax functionality greatly, while giving you the ability to update / add on additional library-like functionality in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "no, there is no available resource that gives you just the AJAX portion of the jQuery library". However, what you can do is go to [code.jquery.com](http://code.jquery.com) and navigate until you find the version that you want. Click the link to that version's `.js` CDN, but NOT their minified version (`.min.js`). Because jQuery is open source, you are permitted to delete everything you don't want, or copy everything that you do want. You will have to do some research into what core functions you will need, and I would suggest that you minify your extracted version when you are done.

Let me know if you have any questions. Good luck! :)