# Handling ajax JSONP with React

Tags: ajax, reactjs, jsonp, webpack-dev-server

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990809/handling-ajax-with-react)

and tried to make cross domain request with jsonp but failed both on webpack dev server and live server.

```
Full code

 official_ajax.jsx   

const UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      login: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.serverPath,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        const title = data[0];
        this.setState ({
        username:title.title,
        login:title.link
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.serverPath, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render:function() {
  return (
  <div>
  {this.state.username} and <a href = {this.state.login}>here</a>
  </div>
  );
 }

});

export default UserGist;

index.jsx

import UserGist from './official_ajax.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
        <div>
        <UserGist serverPath = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/groups_pool.gne?id=807213@N20&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?" />
        </div>
        );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Every time i receive response from server that "connection is not secure".
Every ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *i receive response from server that "connection is not secure"* — Are you sure that's a response from the server and not the browser just refusing to mix HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am not sure. I put live example there http://www.luckyframe74.com/demo/happyReact/src/client/

Comment: Added https, still doesn't work

Comment: Added // istead of http (https) still doesn't work. But connection shows in browser like "secure" already.

Answer (score 0):

I think about that maybe, 
it's https And CORS ( Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) Policy violation.

1. http -> https
2. live Web server add-header (Cors header added)

reference URL ; http://enable-cors.org/index.html