# How to make post request to SOAP endpoint from ReactJS application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, soap, xmlhttprequest, axios

I need to make a `POST` request to `SOAP` endpoint from `ReactJS` application. Is there any npm module that facilitates that or I have to use `node.js` for this. I have no experience on node and would like to keep the implementation to React only if possible.

Can i use `axios` to make a ajax post request to SOAP endpoint? I read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36620094/5346095).
Does `XhrClient` support this?

Any idea how to do this? TIA

Comment: easysoap and npm soap are the 2 node.js packages i know about but they run on the serverside, you need a tool which can be used to call a soap service from the client if i understand you right. [this](https://github.com/doedje/jquery.soap) might be useful in your case

Comment: Can i use axios to make a ajax post request to SOAP endpoint?

Answer (score 2):

You can use packages like [soap-everywhere](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap-everywhere) to interact with a SOAP service from your React app.

Comment: Can i use axios to make a ajax post request to SOAP endpoint?

Comment: @Manu I don't think you can. SOAP is entirely different than REST.

Comment: @Manu, Axios is very famous with the React community, but it doesn't support SOAP. You **can** use it to hit SOAP endpoint, but it won't be a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

[Read this post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967018/how-to-call-soap-web-service-in-react-native/56205348#56205348)

Please follow this answer about consuming SOAP. Hope it helps