# How do you send a request with data to an API in ReactJS that will then respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, ajax

I've been watching videos, reading tutorials, following steps by step and nothing seems to work. Right now, I have this as my code, but my API call is returning 404:

root / server.js

```
const express = require("express");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();

app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.json({ message: "Hello from server!" });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

root / client / app.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import $ from "jquery";

function App() {
  var [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  const api = "http://localhost:3001/api";

  React.useEffect(() => {
    $.post(
      api,
      {
        username: "bobs",
        password: "pizza",
      },
      function (data, status) {
        setData = data;
        console.log(status + " " + data);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  return <>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</>;
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use `jQuery` to do an `AJAX` call to the server.

If (while the server is running - `npm start`) I go to `http://localhost:3001/api`, I get the following message displayed:

> {"message":"Hello from server!"}

This is good - it's what it should say.

When I check my Developer tools (Chrome) > Network, I see the following:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrMlL.png)

[image]

[image]

My apologize if that's too much info - just trying to make sure I cover all my bases.

I also tried the following structures:

[Stackoverflow - Handling ajax with React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29990809/handling-ajax-with-react)

[AJAX and APIs - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

[How to Create a React App with a Node Backend: The Complete Guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-a-react-app-with-a-node-backend-the-complete-guide/)

[How to Set up a Node.js Express Server for React](https://dev.to/pratham10/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-express-server-for-react-2fja)

[YouTube - Call API in React Js | How to send data from frontend to backend react](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qIdC1N2qcQ)

Each one provides me with some kind of error, from CORS, to 404.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If possible, I'd love to stick with `jQuery/AJAX` since I'm most familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the route method is get and you're sending  a post request from react, this is how you  r react code should look

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import $ from "jquery";

function App() {
  var [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  const api = "http://localhost:3001/api";

  React.useEffect(() => {
    $.get( api,{
        username: "bobs",
        password: "pizza",
      },
      function (data, status) {
        setData = data;
        console.log(status + " " + data);
      });
  }, []);

  return <>{!data ? "Loading..." : data}</>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: returns with a CORS error, but the status does show 200, so that's better than it was.

Comment: it's also showing this in the `console.log` : `Uncaught (in promise) {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Comment: you need to use the cors middleware in express 
check this link https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html
for the react code, I was wrong I thought $.get returns a promise. I edited the answer

Comment: You rock - the updated answer and CORS made it work perfectly. `Status: 200`